# Why would JQuery Validation clear values from an unrelated dropdown on fail?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

This ASP.NET Core 7/Razor page project uses JQuery Validation and Unobtrusive Validation.  The page concerned has a [Required] text input field and 2 dropdown lists (these are not marked [Required]).  The lists are populated with the rest of the model on page GET. Each field can be edited and the dropdown values changed as expected.

When I force a validation fail by removing the text in the mandatory field the expected error message is displayed - BUT the 2 dropdown lists have lost all their values and have reverted to the default text.  No postback occurs, which is I believe correct behaviour on failed validation, but the html has changed.

Html before validation failure:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label" for="engagement_CoachingModelId">Coaching model</label>
    <select class="form-control" aria-required="true" id="engagement_CoachingModelId" name="engagement.CoachingModelId">
    <option value="">Please select coaching model</option>
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Model 1</option>
    <option value="3">Model 3</option>
    <option value="4">Model 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Html after validation failure:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="form-label" for="engagement_CoachingModelId">Coaching model</label>
     <select class="form-control" aria-required="true" id="engagement_CoachingModelId" name="engagement.CoachingModelId">
     <option value="">Please select coaching model</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There were two things I was doing wrong:

Firstly, the

```
<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
```

tag was before the jquery script tag in the layout file.  I could have seen this by checking console errors.  Not sure why but I was still getting the initial validation error message but it was then doing a postback but...

Secondly, the on post method in the code behind had the wrong name so it WAS posting back but my method wasn't catching it.

Fixing these 2 mistakes fixed the problem.  Hope this is of some use to someone else one day.